# Angular ui router - nested view inside modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to put a Steps Wizard into a Modal.

Here is my working Wizard: plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/achnwMtmebR3oc8bq7pp?p=preview

Here is my working modal: http://plnkr.co/edit/ux1Ju6m2s9VqiIPjmH1n?p=preview

How do I add this working wizard to a modal? Can nested states be multiple states or limited to no more than two?

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider

        // route to show our basic form (/form)
        .state('form', {
            url: '/form',
            templateUrl: 'form.html',
            controller: 'formController'
        })

        // nested states 
        // each of these sections will have their own view
        // url will be nested (/form/profile)
        .state('form.profile', {
            url: '/profile',
            templateUrl: 'form-profile.html'
        })

        // url will be /form/interests
        .state('form.interests', {
            url: '/interests',
            templateUrl: 'form-interests.html'
        })

        // url will be /form/payment
        .state('form.payment', {
            url: '/payment',
            templateUrl: 'form-payment.html'
        });

    // catch all route
    // send users to the form page 
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/form/profile');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just merge your HTML and JS files, move `ui-view` inside modal
HTML:

```
<body ng-app="formApp">

  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">

    <button type="button" 
            class="btn btn-default"    
            ng-click="mainCtrl.page.open()">Open Modal</button>


    <!-- modal -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
          <!-- views will be injected here -->
          <div class="container">
              <div ui-view></div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default pull-left" 
                type="button" 
                ng-click="modalInstanceCtrl.modal.cancel()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </script>

  </div>



  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
      <div class="jumbotron text-muted text-center">
          <p>a tutorial by <a href="http://scotch.io" target="_blank">scotch.io</a></p>
          <p><a href="http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router">Create a Multi-Step Form Using Angular and UI-Router</a></p>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  </body>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/NaTveRiM5OTufouRo2v7?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

it's better not to put routing inside your modal. You better write your own form steps. The logic is easy. You do not need separate routes. When the "next" button is pressed, you will increase the `pageNumber`. You can put different `div`s for each page. You can hide/show the pages using `ng-show` or `ng-hide` directives.